# Homomorphisms and conjugacy

Tags: group-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

(a) Let $\theta:G→H$ be a homomorphism and let $x,y \in G$. Prove that if $x$ and $y$ are conjugate in $G$ then $\theta(x)$ and $\theta(y)$ are conjugate in $H$.

(b) By considering the homomorphism $\theta :A_5→S_5$, given by $\sigma → \sigma$, or otherwise, show that the converse of the statement in part (a) is false.

Really struggling with this question, don't know where to start - if anyone could shed some light it would be really helpful. Thanks all

Comment: (a) Write an equation expressing the conjugacy of $x$ and $y$. What happens when you take $\theta$ of both sides of that equation?

(b) This amounts to finding two even permutations that are conjugate, but not by an even permutation.

Comment: So so stuck! Literally don't have a clue :(

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x=hyh^{-1}$. Apply $\theta$.

The second question is asking you to find two elements in $A_5$ that are conjugate in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$. Can you do this?

Comment: Literally missed all the lectures on this due to illness and I'm really struggling to grasp it all. Don't have a clue what's going on! :(

Comment: Dear @Melissa: it is quite hard for me to help you to catch up with your class. Maybe you should talk to your classmates and/or professor to get back into rhythm. Maybe then you can come back to this and solve it yourself.